# What are differences between these paths and which one should I use?

Tags: html, path

Suppose I have a file "index.html" and a folder "images" with an image "cats.png" inside.

Then, in the "index.html" file, I specify a path to my image.

Should I use

1. "./images/cats.png" or
2. ".\images\cats.png" or
3. "/images/cats.png" or
4. "\images\cats.png" or
5. "images/cats.png" or
6. "images\cats.png"?

Does the answer vary from system to system (windows or linux) or from technology to technology (html or python or something else)?

Comment: which machine are you using?

Answer (score 0):

- `images\cats.png`: Backslash paths are a convention for windows file system:
- `./` or `.\`: this represents the current directory but when importing files in HTML you don't have to specify it.
- `/images/cats.png` or `\images\cats.png`: starting an path with a slash defines an absolute path from the root directory. In HTML it represents an absolute path relative to your domain root so it may not resolve to the file in some cases (eg: if your index is already in a subdirectory).

In general in HTML you should use forward slashes (`/`) and not use absolute path so the best example would be `images/cats.png`